# Is it possible to set the root directory of a node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

If I publish a node module with source files in a `src` directory, and people would like to import a file in their project, they would need to specify the full path from the module.

Example:

Structure:

```
my-module
--src
----index.js
----something-else.js
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-module",
  "root": "src/index.js"
}
```

Implementation:

```
import myModule from 'my-module';
import somethingElse from 'my-module/src/something-else';
```

(or using `require`)

```
var myModule = require('my-module');
var somethingElse = require('my-module/src/something-else');
```

Is there any way to set up the package so that it knows `src` is my sources root, allowing users to require `somethingElse` with `my-module/something-else`?

If this isn't possible, would it be a good/bad idea to pull the files out of `src` on prepublish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, what is typically done in this instance is either:

1. Have a `something-else.js` file in the root which contains only `require('src/something-else');` Users can then just `require('my-module/something-else');` In this case you have a nicer API which means any changes to your directory structure in future wouldn't break your users code. i.e. you might move `something-else` to `my-module/other-sources/something-else` and you need only change the root file and your users code will still work.
2. You create a core `my-module` which requires everything that your module has available and users can then choose which part of the module via `myModule.somethingElse`

Otherwise, I haven't come across a method to set the sources root explicitly. That option could be handy though if it does exist.

Comment: Note that as of 2021, the "currently applicable answer" sis to use the "new" `exports` field in package.json (see https://medium.com/swlh/npm-new-package-json-exports-field-1a7d1f489ccf etc)

Answer (score 0):

### Possible solutions

#### The Alias

1. Install the [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) package:

   ```
   npm i --save module-alias
   ```
2. Add paths to your `package.json` like this:

   ```js
   {
       "_moduleAliases": {
           "@lib": "app/lib",
           "@models": "app/models"
       }
   }
   ```
3. In your entry-point file, before any `require()` calls:

   ```js
   require('module-alias/register')
   ```
4. You can now require files like this:

   ```js
   const Article = require('@models/article');
   ```

Reference :: https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520